# Connecting 2 tables to associative table with extra column JPA issue

Tags: java, jpa

this is what I have.

[image]
Each time a user purchases a ticket, UserBooking table store userid, timeid and number of tickets purchased. I had UserBooking working when I had userid and timeid but I'm struggling to figure out what to do to add extra column to associative table. When I was working with 2 tables I only had two classes, Users and MovieTimes but I've read that if you want to add extra column you should do following:

**USERS TABLE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Users {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
private int u_id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String type

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="users")
 private List<UserBookings> timeslist;
....
```

**MovieTimes Table**

```
@Entity
public class MovieTimes implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "times_seq")
private int tid;
private String day;
private String time;
private int tickets_qty;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "MovieTimes")
private List<UserBookings> usersList;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "mid")
private Movies m;
```

**UserBookings Table - associative table**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserBookings")
@SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
@IdClass(UserBookingsAssociationId.class)
public class UserBookings {

@Id
private int user_id;
@Id
private int time_id;
@Column(name = "tickets_purchased")
private int tickets_purchased;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="u_id")
private Users u;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="time_id", referencedColumnName="tid")
private MovieTimes mt;
```

**UserBookingsAssociationId Table**

```
public class UserBookingsAssociationId implements Serializable{

private int user_id;

private int time_id;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(user_id + time_id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if(obj instanceof UserBookingsAssociationId){
        UserBookingsAssociationId otherId = (UserBookingsAssociationId) obj;
        return (otherId.user_id == this.user_id) && (otherId.time_id == this.time_id);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem I'm getting while running the code is following:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for    persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):      org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [CinemaPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7154] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
```

Exception Description: The attribute [usersList] in entity class [class model.MovieTimes] has a mappedBy value of [MovieTimes] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class model.UserBookings]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.

Comment: Why not read the message? You have a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL relation, and you set the "mappedBy" to point to a field that doesn't exist! Should have "mappedBy" set to "mt"

Comment: @NeilStockton thanks for answer, I literally had no clue how to do it, found out that I also had to add cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST to Users class, now it works perfectly